# Which one of these models is a better approach in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I am working on a React-Native app and I hosting my data in Cloud Firestore. I have this case where I need to store "restaurant_menu" which contains the menus of all restaurants. 
So, I would like to know which one of these two approached is better.

```
1. restaurants_menu(collection) ->  menu1(document) -> field1, field2, field3, ...

2. restaurants_menu(collection) ->  resturant1_menu(document) -> resturant1_menu (sub-collection) -> field1, field2, field3, ...
```

I am afraid that the first approach is gonna create a huge list of documents later, so instead, I thought maybe the second one is better as it creates a document for each restaurant and then a sub-collection of each menu.

I am not very experienced in no-SQL DB.

Comment: There is really no such thing as a "bad" model, just models that don't meet the needs of your app.  You're going to have to define all of your expected read and write operations, and how much data you actually intend to store.  The best model will derive from your stated use cases.  Again, I suggest posting to a discussion group such as Reddit so you have space to discover what it is you actually need, as there not not just one right answer to this question. https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/

Comment: @DougStevenson but I did explain my case. When the collection of menus grows there will be many documents in that collection, so to avoid that is it a good idea to create subcollections inside documents which are named after each restaurants' id?

Comment: So, are you saying there is going to be a **growing** number of menu items?  Is there an upper limit?  How do you intend to query for them to populate your UI?

Comment: @DougStevenson yes there is will be a growing number of menu items, so to avoid having a huge collection of documents I wanted to create a document for each restaurant which will contain collections of documents with menu items. Over time there will be hundreds of thousands of those items. is it not a good way to create subcollections?

Comment: Firestore doesn't have a problem with "huge" collections.  The size of a collection - the number of documents - is essentially unbounded.  The size limit for fields in a single doucment is 1MB.  What are you concerned about other than that?  How do you intend to query for this data to populate your UI?

Comment: @DougStevenson if I take the first approach, then I will query them based on the "restaurant_id" which is a field in each document.

Comment: Please edit the question to show code of the queries that you expect to use.  Please explain what problems you are concerned about in either case.

Comment: @DougStevenson the only problem I was concerned was about having a big collection of documents, I was not sure if that's gonna affect querying but you are saying that is not gonna be a problem right?

Comment: The performance of Firestore queries is based on the number of documents in your query, not the size of the collection.  I suggest again engaging on a discussion forum such as Reddit to better discuss these issues.  Stack Overflow is for programming questions, and not so good for design and opinion questions.

Comment: @DougStevenson well, a higher number of documents means a bigger size of a collection.

Comment: Yes, that's true. The size of your query is the number of document that you get back.  That's not the total size of the collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the size of a Firestore collection doesn't pose any scalability issues, it seems that neither option is better or worse than the other.  In the absence of more information about how these documents are to be queried and secured, there's not much more to be said.

Comment: well, I already explained how they will be queried. Basically I will query them, all OR single one, based on the restaurant_id which in the first approach will be a field in each document and in the second approach will be a the ID of the document (which will contain sub-collections)

Comment: If that's your only type of query, then it doesn't matter, for the purpose of measuring query performance.

Comment: ok last one, for security reasons is it better to choose the sub-collections?

Comment: You will need to define exactly what your security requirements are before figuring out which is better or more convenient. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started